# Display PDF from web using PDFView

Tags: xamarin.ios, pdfview

I have a pdf that I'm downloading from an api to the local device and trying to use PDFView as I'm trying to not use webview for anything,

my issue is when I get to the PDFView part, I'm following [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-display-pdfs-using-pdfview) tutorial. and I'm stuck on the PdfDocument piece. It keeps saying the path is null.

```cs
var downloadPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "certificate.pdf");
var pdfView = new PdfView
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
};

View.AddSubview(pdfView);

pdfView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
pdfView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
pdfView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.TopAnchor).Active = true;
pdfView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;

// ... HttpClient call to download pdf ...

pdfView.Document = new PdfDocument(new NSUrl(_downloadPath));
```

I excluded the http client piece as that's working no problem, I can detect the file when I tested it.

Comment: try `NSUrl.FromFilename()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is for sure in this line, and I think it should be:

```
pdfView.Document = new PdfDocument(new NSUrl(_downloadPath, false));
```